# Why does extrinsic motivation sometimes reduce intrinsic motivation?

Tags: motivation

Why is it that if a person likes subject X but then when he gets paid for it he doesnt like it anymore. What causes this?

Comment: While this might be the case in some cases (you do not cite what this assumption is based on, so -1), it is important to note this is not always the case! In addition to [the answer provided by H.Muster](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/4212/21), be certain to check out the ['Controversy'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overjustification_effect#Controversy) section on the linked Wikipedia page. E.g., _"In fact, a 2001 meta-analysis showed that rewards can increase intrinsic motivation for tasks that initially hold little intrinsic interest."_

Answer (score 10):

This effect has been termed [Overjustification effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overjustification_effect) and was originally reported by Lepper, Greene & Nisbett (1973) who studied the influence of rewards on intrinsic motivated behavior.

Some theories hypothesize that the reward reduces the feeling of self-determination, which in turn reduces intrinsic motivation, because the reward induces the feeling of being controlled by the person that offered the reward.

**References**

Lepper MR, Greene D, Nisbett RE (1973). Undermining children's intrinsic interest with extrinsic reward: A test of the 'overjustification' hypothesis. Journal of Personality and Social Psychology 28 (1): 129–137. doi:10.1037/h0035519.

Comment: As a reference, I would like to add the cognitivie evaluation theory (Deci) and Motivation Crowding Theory (Frey)

Comment: This answer might need to be qualified in order to take into account [this is not _always_ the case](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/4211/why-does-extrinsic-motivation-sometimes-reduce-intrinsic-motivation#comment39798_4211).

Answer (score 1):

To understand Extrinsic motivation to do something think of the carrot and the stick theory. So one only does something because they have to, ie, for some reward for due to some fear of penalty. Think of when our parents "made" us do the dishes. Thats an example of an extrinsically motivated act. Whereas Intrinsic motivation  is when we do something because we want to. So sometimes what starts out as an extrinsic motivation becomes internalised within our belief system and it actually becomes somewhat intrinsic. for example, our parents instil in us to brush our teeth every night and then when we become parents that becomes our own own intrinsic value. however without going into too much detail, it is still an extrinsic motivation while being classified as a subset of extrinsic motivation because it has almost the most of the elements of intrinsic motivation the only difference being is that it is an internalised extrinsic motivation. So to address the question, the extrinsic motivation has not interfered with the intrinsic motivation. 
A study showed that once a reward was offered to people who were intrinsically motivated, they actually lost interest. however when praise was offered instead of reward, the intrinsic motivation was maintained or increased.

References
Deci, E., & Ryan, R. (Eds.), (2002). Handbook of self-determination research. Rochester, NY: University of Rochester Press

Comment: *Disclaimer* my friend answered this question on my account, I am trying to get my friends to create their own accounts and answer questions *sigh* lol